# Bitnami Nginx AWS Lightsail .htaccess location

Tags: nginx, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Where is the .htaccess file located, I can't seem to find it.

Their [docs list apache](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/nginx/administration/use-htaccess/), which I don't have.

Comment: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and the related subdirectories are how Nginx is usually configured. Those Bitnami docs seem to be incorrect, or at least poorly presented in a way that implies `.htaccess` is useful with Nginx. See also [the docs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/).

Comment: `.htaccess` is for apache only, nginx not accessing and won't need `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thanks @ZacAnger I was able to do what I needed through nginx.conf